# What are the most effective unit upgrades in Atom Zombie Smasher?

Tags: atom-zombie-smasher

What do you find to be the most effective unit upgrades in Atom Zombie Smasher, and why?

#### Evac Helicopter

- **Arrival Time** or **Load Time**?

#### Artillery

- **Impact Time** or **Reload Time**?

#### Zed Bait

- **Range**, **Lifetime**, or **Reload Time**?

#### Infantry

- **Accuracy** or **Speed**?

#### Snipers

- **Refire Time** or **Reposition Time**?

Comment: I am not entirely sure there is a "correct" answer to this question. Off the top of my head, having infantry move faster allows them to effectively control a larger zone, but increasing their accuracy makes them better at not letting Zs through. Which is better? That depends on the situation, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Evac Helicopter**

**Arrival Time** is my preference.  The faster it shows up, the faster I can get civilians out.  Load time is so short as to be inconsequential, really. (EDIT: As was pointed out in the comments) **Load Time** becomes more important if you increase the helicopter capacity by research - if you don't have faster load times, it may not fill entirely before lifting off.

**Artillery**

**Reload Time** is what I've found to be most useful, as it lets me fire more.  That said, without good Impact Time, it's hart to accurately target.  I keep these close to even, so it can shoot again as soon as the shells land.

**Zed Bait**

I'd say **Range or Reload Time**.  I must admit, I rarely use this enough to level it significantly.

**Infantry**

**Accuracy** has always been my first choice.  It stops more zeds, and if you structure your forces right, you end up funneling most of the to your infantry, so they don't have to move much.

**Snipers**

**Refire Time**, definitely.  Position them well at the start (I like a corner, with a target point across the map) and they can cover as many as half of the zed entry points.  This is wonderful when combined with artillery strikes on those areas.  Faster firing means more dead zed, and that leads to faster leveling of your snipers, and fewer victory points for the bad guys.

Comment: I disagree with the heli - if you upgrade the hold size of the helicopter (once you can research) you'll find you need to shorten load time otherwise the heli doesn't manage to fill up before it has to take off again.

Comment: @DMA57361: That may be true, but I've never increased hold size.  I always found that increased XP speed and faster scientists were better buys.  If you increase the hold capacity, though, load time might be worth buying up.

Comment: With Zed Bait, all of the options are good, but reload time is the best, as it means you can often get a second shot with it before night hits. This can be useful for pulling the last stragglers together and then wiping them out for a Complete Victory.